# SVN Import Force for importing existing file

Tags: svn

I am creating a text file and a ZIP file for a tag automatically with MSBuild. My MSBuild project is called by [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl).

The text file is always going to be `latest.txt` and the ZIP file will be `(version).zip` (so it will be different every time). I do not want to commit these files back to my trunk nor check out the tags directory.

Hence, I discovered `svn import`. The first time it works for both. On successive runs, it fails since `latest.txt` already exists in the repository. Do I need to use `svn import --force` or something else to get these two files pushed up to my repository?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. It seems like you said that you don't want to commit the files, but you are having trouble committing them? Are you looking for "svn ignore"?

Comment: No, I want to put them in my repository without the checkout, add, commit cycle. Have a look at `svn import`.

Comment: Right, but if they are unversioned files, why are you trying to import latest.txt more than once?

Comment: `latest.txt` changes with every build. I just want to store that information everytime.

Comment: Then latest.txt should be a versioned file and committed with each new build.

Comment: The problem with that is that it would make two commits and it does not support my directory structure.

Comment: You are definitely not using import the way it was meant to be used. I agree with Kevin, this really is a versioned file and you should commit it. Depending on your needs, you may even want to generate this file or update it as part of a post-commit hook or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the answer to the question would be to only `svn import` the `(version).zip` file. Since the contents of `latest.txt` change for each build, it is a versioned file and should be committed as such.

Comment: How do I add it to this path without downloading all the files on a checkout?

Answer (score 4):

`svn import` allows you to commit an unversioned file into the repository. If it is a new file on the repo, it works fine. But you cannot use `svn import` to commit to an existing path.

The workaround then would be to **delete the repo file first, and then import it back again**.

- Delete command: `svn delete URL -m "deleting for update"`
- Import command: `svn import PATH URL -m "<your message here>"`

**You will lose the file history**, but it's a nice way of making straightforward updates to simple files; and since you don't care about versioning, it should suit your needs.

Comment: `svn delete` and `svn import` again should be the accepted answer IMO.